# Compute $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(x)}{(x^2 + a^2)(x^2 + b^2)}dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I wish to compute  $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(x)}{(x^2 + a^2)(x^2 + b^2)}dx$ using complex analysis, but if that isn't possible using just regular calculus is fine.

$a>0, a \neq b$

I was thinking that since the singularities are $\pm i\sqrt{a}$, $\pm i\sqrt{b}$, that we could apply the cauchy residue theorem, but I didn't know how to choose a contour for the integral.

Comment: Extend the integral to the whole real line. Then try the semi circle contour avoiding the singularities on the real line. By the way, the $b$ singularities are $\pm i\sqrt b$

Comment: Use parity to get an integral over $\mathbb{R}$. Replace $\sin x$ with $e^{ix}$ (you then want the imaginary part of the resulting integral). Use a large semicircle.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't understand. Could please provide an answer so I can see what you mean?

Comment: @complex.me your question is similar to [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263745/computing-the-complex-integral). Do you know Jordan's lemma?

Comment: @kobe i'm familiar with it, but eh. I don't understand how you knew that we wanted the imaginary part of that function though.

Comment: @complex.me recall that Jordan's lemma concerns integrals of the form $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{iax}\, dx$.

Comment: @complex.me so to use the lemma in this context, I must relate your integral to one of those types of integrals. This is where the imaginary part idea comes in.

Comment: Ah, okay. Still a bit tricky I think.